# Distributing Medals solution in Java

Tags: java

Distributing Medals  It's the medal distribution ceremony. 10^6 police officers, numbered from 1 to 10^6, are standing in a line. There are `N (1<=N<=1000)` iterations of medal distribution. In iteration `i` `(0 < = i < N), count[i] ( 1 < = count[i] < = 100)` medals are given to all officers from `from[i] to to[i] ( 1 < = from[i] < = to[i] < = 10^6 )`

If we sum up the number of medals received starting from the first officer, who would be the first officer for which the cumulative sum exceeds a given medal `count THRESHOLD ( 1 < = THRESHOLD < = 10^9 )`?

Input/Output Specifications Input format:

You are given 5 inputs:

1. input1 = N, the number of iterations
2. input2 = count, the array of medal counts in each iteration
3. input3 = from, the array of starting indices in each iteration
4. input4 = to, the array of ending indices in each iteration
5. input5 = THRESHOLD, the medal count threshold

Output format:

An integer, representing the number of the first officer such that the cumulative sum of medals starting from the first officer upto this officer exceeds THRESHOLD. The output should be -1 if such an officer does not exist.

Comment: YOu need to start with your algorithm and make some code. If that does not work, ask here for help with your code.

Comment: actually i failed to understand what is exactly problem..  what i have to do basically

Answer (score 0):

It's work in c# language

```
public static int DistributingMedals(int input1, int[] input2, int[] input3, int[] input4, int input5)
{
    int officerIndex = -1;
    if (InputsValid(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5))
    {
        int medalsCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input1; i++)
        {
            for (int o = input3[i]; o <= input4[i]; o++)
            {
                medalsCount += input2[i];
                if (medalsCount > input5)
                {
                    officerIndex = o;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (medalsCount > input5)
                break;
        }
    }
    return officerIndex;
}

private static bool InputsValid(int input1, int[] input2, int[] input3, int[] input4, int input5)
{
    if (((1 <= input1) && (input1 <= 1000))
        && ((input2.Length == input1) && (input3.Length == input1) && (input4.Length == input1))
        && ((1 <= input5) && (input5 <= 1000000000)))
    {
        int ok = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input1; i++)
        {
            if ((1 <= input3[i] && input3[i] <= input4[i] && input4[i] <= 1000000)
                && (1 <= input2[i] && input2[i] <= 100))
                ok++;
        }
        if (ok == input1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is not pass all the test case, only one test case it pass.

Comment: could you give your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Java#
-----------------------

public class CandidateCode 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int answer = DistributingMedals(1,new int[]{1},new int[]{1},new int[]{10},2);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param input1 = N, the number of iterations
     * @param input2 = count, the array of medal counts in each iteration
     * @param input3 = from, the array of starting indices in each iteration
     * @param input4 = to, the array of ending indices in each iteration
     * @param input5 = THRESHOLD, the medal count threshold

     * @return
     */

    public static int DistributingMedals(int input1,int[] input2,int[] input3,int[] input4,int input5)
    {

        int officerIndex = -1;
        if (InputsValid(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5))
        {
            int medalsCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < input1; i++)
            {
                for (int o = input3[i]; o <= input4[i]; o++)
                {
                    medalsCount += input2[i];
                    if (medalsCount > input5)
                    {
                        officerIndex = o;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (medalsCount > input5)
                    break;
            }
        }
        return officerIndex;

    }   


    private static boolean InputsValid(int input1, int[] input2, int[] input3, int[] input4, int input5)
    {
        if (((1 <= input1) && (input1 <= 1000))
            && ((input2.length == input1) && (input3.length == input1) && (input4.length == input1))
            && ((1 <= input5) && (input5 <= 1000000000)))
        {
            int ok = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < input1; i++)
            {
                if ((1 <= input3[i] && input3[i] <= input4[i] && input4[i] <= 1000000)
                    && (1 <= input2[i] && input2[i] <= 100))
                    ok++;
            }
            if (ok == input1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```